# Dropbox Api for .net Rename File

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api, file-rename

I am using Dropbox ApI V2. I want to rename file name using this api with .NET and C#. Is there any method for that just like below?

```
async Task Rename(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string oldfileName, string newfileName)
{
    var response = await dbx.Files.RenameFile("");
}
```

If not than what is the other solution. Please tell me.
Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220574/how-to-use-dropbox-api-v2-to-rename-a-file

Comment: Thank You, but its http request.. I want to use DropboxClient class. Is there any method in that?

Answer (score 2):

Ever since Windows was created, for renaming they actually were using `move` command, where they set the same folder in destination, but use different name for the file.

**For .NET Dropbox Api V2 [link on git](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/):**

You might use the method `MoveAsync()` located in the `FilesUserRoutes` class. [official link](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_MoveAsync_1.htm)

```
public Task<Metadata> MoveAsync(
    string fromPath,
    string toPath,
    bool allowSharedFolder = false,
    bool autorename = false
)
```

For the example, You would use it like:

```
new Dropbox.Api.DropboxClient("AccessToken").Files.MoveAsync("FromFile","ToFile");
```

**For HTTP / JSON API:**

see Q: [How to use Dropbox API v2 to rename a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220574/how-to-use-dropbox-api-v2-to-rename-a-file)

API docs: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-move

**from_path** *String(pattern="(/(.|[\r\n])*)|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)")* - Path in the user's Dropbox to be copied or moved.

**to_path** *String(pattern="(/(.|[\r\n])*)|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)")* - Path in the user's Dropbox that is the destination.

**allow_shared_folder** *Boolean* - If true, copy will copy contents in shared folder, otherwise RelocationError.cant_copy_shared_folder will be returned if from_path contains shared folder. This field is always true for move. The default for this field is False.

**autorename** *Boolean* - If there's a conflict, have the Dropbox server try to autorename the file to avoid the conflict. The default for this field is False.

```
{
    "from_path": "/Homework/math",
    "to_path": "/Homework/algebra",
    "allow_shared_folder": false,
     "autorename": false
}
```